# How to modify arrow path?

Tags: graphviz, dot

How to have arrow 2 have the same shape as arrow 1?

[image]

```
digraph {
    rankdir=LR
    label = "Lý thuyết ý định hành động";
    labelloc = t
    labeljust = r
    fontsize = 20
    fontname = Lato
    overlap=false;

    a [ label = "Thái độ của\nbản thân đối\nvới hành động" ]
    b [ label = "Cảm nhận về\nthế nào là\nchuẩn mực" group=g1]
    c [ label = "Cảm nhận về\nkhả năng đạt\nđược kết quả" ]
    
    d [ label = "Có ý định hành động" group=g1 style=rounded shape=polygon ]
    e [ label = "Thực sự hành động" group=g1 style=rounded shape=box3d ]
    
    { rank=same; a, b, c }
    a:w -> b:w [ label="" dir=both]
    a:w -> c:w [ label="                 " dir=both]
    b:w -> c:w [ label="" dir=both]
    a:e -> d:n [ label="1" ]
    b:e -> d:w
    c:e -> d:s [ label="2" ]
    d -> e
    c -> e:s [style=dashed dir=none]
}
```

<sub>By the way, the left arrows can only be that symmetric when I put empty labels to them. Is there any explanation for this?</sub>

Comment: It is a strange effect, but as soon as 2 arrows dock at the same side this looks like to happen, changing `c -> e:s [style=dashed dir=none]` to `c:s -> e:s [style=dashed dir=none]` removes the problem.

Comment: It doesn't change for me

Comment: Which version of dot? I tried with 2.38.0 and 2.40.1 an both looked OK to me with the change.

Comment: I use 2.47.1 (20210417.1919)

Comment: I quickly tried with 2.47.1 (I had de zip file with the executable available ...) and the results look OK as well, strange.

Comment: Btw. what is the command line you use? (I used `dot -T png aa.dot > aa.png`)

Comment: My command is simply `dot -Tpng input.gv -o output.png`. Since this seems to be a bug, I report this in [the GraphViz forum](https://forum.graphviz.org/t/how-to-modify-arrow-path/705?u=ooker)